# Dynamic Variable Names for Android App

Tags: android, settext

I have an activity with 4 TextView elements with ids of Mon1, Mon2, Mon3, Mon4.

Is it possible to create a loop in the MainActivity.java code where I can perform, for example, a setText action on each of the 4 ids without having to list them out one-by-one.

ie.  Mon**X**.setText=""; (where **X** is a value from 1 to 4).

I guess to take this one step further, if the ids were actually Mon1, Mon2, Mon3, Mon4, Tue1, Tue2, Tue3, Tue4, Wed1 .........Sun1, Sun2,Sun3, Sun4.  Could a loop be created to not only change the number 1..4 but also use an array for the Mon, Tue, Wed etc.

The end result being some sort of loop that can do setText on ALL the ids that I need rather than 28 individual setText commands.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
TextView Mon1; //and do whatever with it
TextView Mon2; //And so on

TextView[] tv = {Mon1, Mon2, Mon3, /*etc*/}
int i = 0;

void doSomething(){while(i<=/*number of TextViews*/){tv[i].setText("BLAH");i++;}}
```

I hope this helped :D

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.  I knew I needed to use arrays but being new to android / java coding, it was just finding out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a loop in the MainActivity.java code where I
>   can perform, for example, a setText action on each of the 4 ids
>   without having to list them out one-by-one.

Yup.  Use an array.

To take it another step further, use another array.  It's what they're made for.

(By array, I mean an ArrayList, HashMap, dictionary, array, or any other data structure like that).